# About ARC function

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm new to iOS world. I'm reading 2 books now to learn how to develop iOS app.

Following are the books.

1. Head First iPhone Development (it is old book, it uses ARC and MRC simultaneously)
2. Objective-C

My question is that I have just met ARC (automatic reference counting) and I want to know how much iOS developer use ARC nowdays.

It is quite difficult for me to understand ARC so if it is not popular function, I just want to pass it and I just want to use MRC (manual reference counting).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: But ARC is vastly simpler than MRC. What are you finding difficult about it?

Comment: This question is likely to result in mostly opinion-based answers. SO is more geared towards helping you debug code that you have written rather than choosing which technology to use.

Comment: @Kmeixner In this case, probably not. It's likely fact that ARC is popular and the OP should use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see some iOS projects on http://github.com and you will find almost all the projects nowadays are using ARC.
Of course there are some old projects using MRC.
I suggest you just ignore the memory management on iOS at the beginning. The compile will use ARC to help you with it automatically.
After that, you will understand ARC more and more clearly in the way learning iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody uses ARC. Almost no projects use MRC any more.

> It is quite difficult for me to understand ARC

If you understand MRC, just think of ARC as automatically inserting `retain` and `release` calls into your code at the appropriate places at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

ARC is much better than MRC. I suggest you to start with ARC. You can ask the specific difficulties in ARC.

There are also commands to use MRC files/projects in ARC and vice versa.

Handling "retain" and "release" manually is quite difficult with MRC.